# Swift 4+SwiftyJson convert/generate objects from JSON automatically

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJSON to get a JSON from my web service. What's the easiest way to convert this into a swift object represenation?

I mean maybe a website like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which does the same for Java.

I so far found generators which work from String or Dictionary but not SwiftyJSON?

Thanks

Comment: The best option is to get rid of SwiftyJSON and use the built in JSONDecoder and Decodable.

Comment: I think you might be right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [json4swift](http://www.json4swift.com)

[image]

**Online JSON to Swift Models Generator**

Our motive is simple, in this age of technology; convenience and automation, working with JSON for Swift shouldn't be complicated anymore. Without dependency on other tools and framework, this free online utility maps your web service responses to appropriate models. It makes working with JSON easier and manageable.

**Free Utility**

This online free utility generates a Swift 2.0 and Swift 4.0 compatible models which can be simply dragged & used in your project.

**Map Response**

Simply map your web service response with your models with a single line.

**Dictionary Representation**

The objects can be referred to as a dictionary anytime should you need them with the current state and same key-value pairs.

Answer (score 11):

You can see [JSON Master](https://jsonmaster.github.io), Here you can generate you code directly from `JSON` for `SwiftyJSON`, `Codable` framework or classical `Dictionary`. It can also generate `struct` or `class`.

Also it has support for Java, Kotlin and C#

Comment: Way better than the other options found in a quick google search. None of the options actually provided full encode() and decode() support except for this, and I tried at least 5.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for example you have a `Student Model` and you want to map the `JSON Object` to `Student Object`. You can try like this:

```
struct Student {

  let id: Int!
  let name: String!

  init(param: JSON) {
    id = param["id"].intValue
    name = param["name"].stringValue
  }

  /* JSON Response
  {
    "id": 168,
    "name": "KoingDev"
  }
  */

}
```

Hope it is useful! :)

Comment: Well yeah, its good if you have simple classes with few parameters. I have 50 with dozens of parameters each. hence generally I'm using generative tools to do stuff like this.